# How to get worksheet rows count in spreadsheet gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there any attribute to get size of rows?

```
@sheet = Spreadsheet.open(file.path).worksheet 0
@sheet.rows_count # why they didn't it?
```

Answer (score 4):

They did it, in fact => `@sheet.count`

Comment: Anybody know how to do this with RubyXL?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using RubyXL use the below to get the row count.

`rowCount = worksheet.sheet_data.rows.size
 colCount = worksheet.cols.size`